# Improvement of my code that reads STL files (c++)

Tags: string, file, import, stl, directx

in order to create a 3D simulation with DirectX I have to import huge datasets in ASCII-STL format. The thing is that my reader is working but the performance is terrible. I made a comparision with the Autodesk Inventor STL importer and the different is significant (5sec vs 1.5min). I'd highly appreciate suggestions or ideas to improve my code. Thank you!

Furthermore, the STL format is very inefficient. For each face the vertices are listed seperately. It looks like the follwing:

facet normal 0 0.999229 0.0392606

outer loop

vertex -3173.54 1993.84 -23184.5

vertex -3099.94 1993.84 -23184.5

vertex -3099.94 2000 -23341.5

endloop

endfacet

The result is that vertices occur several times during the processing of the file. I tried to check for double vertices but it takes forever for huge files (iterations become longer and longer).

Here is my code so far:

```
    std::ifstream stlFile;
stlFile.open(mFilename);
if(!stlFile) // check if file can be found
{
    MessageBox(0, "STL file not found.", 0, 0);
    return false;
}

std::string ignore;
stlFile >> ignore >> ignore; //ignore header: solid t=x.xx
UINT index = 0;

int iIndex = 0;
int vIndex = 0;
WORD indexTmp = 0;

while(1)
{
    stlFile >> ignore >> ignore; // ignore "normal"
    if (ignore == "CUBE")
        break;

    float normal[3];

    stlFile >> normal[0] >> normal[1] >> normal[2]; // read and save the face normal
    stlFile >> ignore >> ignore; // ignore "outer loop"
    for(int i = 0; i <= 2; ++i) // read the three vertices of a face
    {
        VERTEX vertexTmp;
        vertexTmp.Normal.x = normal[0]; vertexTmp.Normal.y = normal[1]; vertexTmp.Normal.z = normal[2];
        stlFile >> ignore >> vertexTmp.Pos.x >> vertexTmp.Pos.y >> vertexTmp.Pos.z;// >> ignore >> ignore;  

        //if (!ContainsVertexIndex(vertexTmp, vertices, indexTmp)) // return vertex index of double 
        //{
            mVertices.push_back(vertexTmp); //save newly created vertex     

            indexTmp = vIndex; // create index reference to the new vertex
            vIndex++; // increment index
        //}
        mIndices.push_back(indexTmp);
        iIndex++; // increment index
    }
    stlFile >> ignore >> ignore; // endloop // endfacet
}

stlFile.close();
```

Edit: I changed the vectors to fixed arrays but the performance does not increase significantly. Any other suggestions.

Comment: Which data structures are `mVertices` and `mIndices`? Lists, Vectors? As a quick guess, I think your time is eaten by memory allocation by pushing your additional elements. For complex files, these costs shouldn't be underestimated.

Comment: Sorry for not mentioning it. It's vectors. Yes it was my guess that the dynamic allocation takes some extra time. I wish I could use standard arrays but the problem is that STL files (unlike many other file formats) don't tell the number of vertices and faces in the beginning of the file.

Answer (score 2):

I just came across this question and have a bit of insight into your speed problem.

You shouldn't be using a vector for data storage of this type. Since you're constantly checking for the existence of vertices in the vector, you're wasting a lot of time iterating over the vector.

A much easier way is creating a hashmap of vertices. This allows for constant-time lookup (which isn't really needed) and insertion which is where your processing bottleneck is. Your total runtime would then be O(n) where n is number of triangles processed.

You need to be able to hash your VERTEX objects which can be done by creating a template for hashing. I found this is easiest to do using Boost's hashing library, but you can write your own.

```
namespace std
{
     template<>
     struct hash<your_namespace::VERTEX>
     {
          typedef your_namespace::VERTEX argument_type;
          typedef size_t result_type;

          result_type operator()(const argument_type &v) const
          {
               result_type seed = 0;

               boost::hash_combine(seed, v.X);
               boost::hash_combine(seed, v.Y);
               boost::hash_combine(seed, v.Z);

               return seed;
          }
     }
}
```

Boost's hash_combine method creates hashes that are unique based on the order you hash the variables. So X->Y->Z produces a different hash than Z->Y->X (and therefore each sequence combination produces a unique output).

Finally, use a map data structure to store the VERTEX data objects.

```
// declaration
std::map<std::size_t, VERTEX> hashmap;

// adding VERTEX object
hashmap[std::hash<VERTEX>()(vObject)] = vObject;
```

Using this method, you won't have to worry about inserting more than one of each coordinate set since hashing the coordinate set infers removing duplicates. Therefore no more checking for duplicates by looping over a vector data structure.

Hope this helps. I had the same bottlenecking problem and this reduced my STL reading time from minutes to milliseconds.